# Why do I get "protected namespace - access denied" on p4 sync in zsh but not bash?

Tags: perforce, zsh

I'm trying Oh My Zsh on my Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug) machine. I'm getting "../.. - protected namespace - access denied." when I do a `p4 sync`:

```
➜  dev p4 login
Enter password:
User dspitzer logged in.
➜  dev p4 sync ...
../.. - protected namespace - access denied.
```

It works fine in bash:

```
$ p4 login
Enter password:
User dspitzer logged in.
$ p4 sync ...
... - file(s) up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the shell is interpreting the `...` token. Try putting single quotes around it like this:

```
$ p4 sync '...'
```

Comment: That was it. Apparently zsh coverts "..." to "../..". Bonus points to anyone who finds where that is documented. (I can't find it.)

Comment: @DarylSpitzer It sounds like you use `oh-my-zsh`; `.oh-my-zsh/lib/aliases` contains `alias ...='cd ../..'`

Comment: @chepner There is no `aliases` file in `.oh-my-zsh/lib/`. Perhaps I have a different version of `oh-my-zsh`. I can't find a `...` alias.

Comment: I put `alias ...="..."` in my .zshrc, which solved the problem.

Comment: @DarylSpitzer You could also use `unalias -a ...`